# Python - cant access variables from higher scope when using Multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Im running my script with this, and for some reason, i get a " intervals_input not defined" error, since for some reason the main() function now cannot access the variables from outside.

```
def main():
    foo = AutoGambler()
    foo.Main(intervals=intervals_input,weaponPos=weaponPos_input,gamblePos=gamblePos_input,wipePos=wipePos_input,colors="cyan")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    intervals_input = input("Repeat how often? (X for infinite, default 10)") or 10
    weaponPos_input = input("What square is your weapon on? (e.g. 5th from left, 3rd from top => '5-3')")
    gamblePos_input = input("What square is your gamble on?")
    wipePos_input = input("What square is your wipe on?")

    freeze_support()
    print("start")
    Process(target=main).start()
```

When i run `main()` normally without multiprocessor that isnt the case. How can i solve this, and why can it no longer access the variables?

Comment: 'i get a "not defined" error'—You should probably post all the detail of the error message.

Comment: Processes (as used by `multiprocessing`) run in separate memory space, so variables are not shared - pass them as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass parameters to the new Process explicetely with the `args` parameter.

`Process(target=main, args=(intervals_input , weaponPos_input ,...))`

Of course you need to change your `main` to have input arguments with something like `main(*args)`.

Also, please note that once passed they have no relation with the original ones.